Can I put a 11-42 cassette on 24-38 chainrings?
I have mountainbike 2*10 gears with 24-38 chainrings and a 11-36 cassette.
I need to change cassetre and thinking about bigger one because I ride steep long uphills.
Will this setup works?

Derailleur:
SHIMANO RD-M4120-SGS DEORE
10/11
Cassette:
SHIMANO Deore CS-M4100-10spd 11-42T
Chain:
SHIMANO HG54 DEORE 10sp

Thanks you.

Iffy. The listed max front capacity is 10 and total capacity is 41, so you are 4 teeth over in front.

Welcome to the site - whatever happens, please do come back and fill us in with your progress.  Photos would be awesome too, thanks.

Maybe.
Looking at https://www.bike-components.de/en/Shimano/Deore-Shadow-RD-M4120-10-11-speed-Rear-Derailleur-p77728/ the specs are:

Cage Length: SGS
Max. Largest Sprocket Teeth: 42 teeth
Min. Largest Sprocket Teeth: 42 teeth
Max. Smallest Sprocket Teeth: 11 teeth
Min. Smallest Sprocket Teeth: 11 teeth
Max. Chainring Difference: 10 teeth
Total Capacity: 41 teeth

So the difference between your front chainrings is 38-24 or 14 teeth
I suspect the rear shifting will work fine.   If you were changing to the matching front derailleur, then front shifts may be a bit hard.
However your parts list suggests you're staying wiht the existing front shifter/derailleur.   That will work as well as it does now for shifting, with the main risk being a bit of saggy chain in the small:small combos.
Upshot - avoid running in small:small and any gear combo where the bottom run of chain hits the jockey wheel.

Although implicitly implied, I think it is worth stating explicitly, as the capacity is being exceeded, it is really important to ensure the chain is long enough for the Large/Large combo. If too short, damage is likely if someone tries to change to Large/Large.

I have a bike with the clutched version of the M4120 and a 46/30 crankset (so 16T front difference). The chain is sized for the large-large combination (very important, as pointed in the comments), so the chain sags in the small-small combination and hits the chainstay in this combination when the terrain is rough, but shifting is otherwise fine.
But if you plan to replace the rear derailleur as well (I'm surprised that a M4120 would be spec'ed for an 11-36 cassette, but that's possible) and your chainring is an 10-speed one, you can also use an 11-speed cassette (you'll need matching, shifters and chain). Going to 11-speed opens two possibilities: the RD-M8000-SGS, that meets all the specs, but my favourite option would be the CUES U6020 (2x11), that is designed for an 11/45 cassette and a 16T front difference. CUES cassettes are supposed to be more durable (no lab measure at this stage), so even it's more expensive upfront, the difference will be compensated by less frequent cassette replacements.

Thank you for your answer. So I don't intend to use any combination small-small (24-11) or big-big (38-42). There is much between not to use those not-recommended gear combinations. I have driven more than 30 years and never used any of those combinations. Except on bike stand when fine tuning. It is not a problem one speed click on the rear shifter before changing front (I don't do any races, just driving for my pleasure :-)).

The whole parts are about 110€ and when taking in consideration that my cassette and chain however need replacement soon it seams to me like nice upgrade. The only "bad" thing is that I'm removing XT rear derailleur (Shimano XT GS Shadow Plus) to put Deore instead. This is the bike
https://archive.superiorbikes.com/en/2015/mtb-race/mtb-race-fs/663-xf-917.html
The first idea was to go to 111 or 112 setup but it seems too slow for me for flats and downhills.

@DamirTafra most of the “XT experience” comes from the shifter. From Deore, it’s quite hard to make the difference between an Deore and a matching XT. But the difference of the shifter is noticeable.

My shifters are Shimano SLX I-spec Rapid Fire Plus 2x10 so I hope it schould be fine with Deore deailleur
